# TestNg Link broken not found

Tags: testng

Is the link for testNG changed as I’m getting forbidden when i try to access

(http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/)

I tried from many networks and I’m still cannot access it so I’m totally blocked to install the plugin

Comment: u mean its not working when installing in eclipse? straightway URL will not work in browser

Comment: It’s not working anyways